# Where are app folders from the "Show applications" window defined?

Tags: gnome, directory, appmenu

## Problem

Every single time I install something from the snap-store (doesn't have to be a snap app, a .deb file also counts) all of my nicely organized programs inside their own folders scatter themselves everywhere and the folders disappear.
This is how they should look:[image]
And after this window gets updated with a new program, everything BUT the "Utilities" folder disappears and all my apps are scattered around as if they went back to factory settings.

## Relevant information

I'm running a non-LTS Ubuntu 20.10 installation.

This might be related to my user name change I did a couple of days ago, are these connected to my user? Maybe a file didn't update the new home directory path or some similar problem.

## Troubleshooting

I've tried to search for the location of the file or filesystem that organizes these things in the background but to no avail, I can't find information online.

Comment: Add your Ubuntu version to your post - probably 20.10. This is erroneous behavior, a.k.a. buggy. A newly installed application should appear in the top level next to your groups without removing them, and then you can drag it into a group.

Comment: My fault! It is 20.10 but I completely forgot to add it.

Comment: Perhaps a read on this might point you in the right direction: https://developer.gnome.org/AppFolders/

Comment: OK, you added some "relevant information" including a change in user name. So there will be the cause. Start over with a fresh and new user account.

Comment: I'm not sure this was an issue directly related to that. I changed my user name very early on my installation, it might be something else